# jsPlumb: How to make the modification from division to endpoint?

Tags: javascript, connection, endpoint, yui3, jsplumb

I have dynamical created nodes (by yui3 library).
All nodes created as children of the same parent as html-elements.

However in terms of design some of nodes must be endpoints of other elements.

For connections drawing I use jsPlumb library.

Example.

HTML-code:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="window" style="height: 150; width: 100; top: 50; left:50">parent</div>
  <div class="ep" style="height: 10; width: 10; top: 55; left:45">1</div>
  <div class="ep" style="height: 10; width: 10; top: 70; left:45">2</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want that "1" and "2" elements will be endpoints of "parent"-element.

All elements should be draggable and "children" divisions should be moving together with "parent" division.

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks for your attention, Eugene.

Questions:

- how to make existing division as endpoint of other element (node)?
- how to drag list of elements by dragging "parent" element?
- solution with yui3 using will be very useful also.

My research:

- There is "addEndpoint" function in jsPlumb library. But this function create new node for endpoint. I don't understand approach for drawing endpoint with my design (i.e. not standard rectangles or circles) and correct approach of the some element attributes setting.
- I tried to make the hierarchical html-document but that case was generating next problem: connections drawn at child layer. After several weeks of attempts of correct this bug I chose current version.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from question

> There is "addEndpoint" function in jsPlumb library. But this function create new node for endpoint. I don't understand approach for drawing endpoint with my design (i.e. not standard rectangles or circles) and correct approach of the some element attributes setting.

Docs - http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/endpoints.html

There are various ways to customize the endpoint, of course using your own html element, will be trouble-some and I don't see a good reason to do that (better to have stuff in jsPlumb context, since there are lots of handlers/events/querying to take care of). You can customize everything about the endpoint.

Demos - http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/

If you've already tried something regarding the look & feel of endpoint and it didn't worked, you can let us know. IMHO the ability to use image as an endpoint fulfills all use-cases.

Here's how to remove connections & endpoints :

```
jsPlumb.getConnections({
            //source: id (you can delete selectively by querying what you want)
        }).forEach(function (conn) {
             jsPlumb.detach(conn);
        });

jsPlumb.selectEndpoints({
            //source: id (you can delete selectively by querying what you want)
        }).each($.proxy(function (ele) {
            var uuid = ele.getUuid();
            jsPlumb.deleteEndpoint(uuid);
        }, this));
```

There are also short-hands like :

```
jsPlumb.deleteEveryEndpoint();

jsPlumb.detachEveryConnection();
```

Comment: This approach (with yui3-nodes as endpoints) is motivated by need to use tabview for drawing several graph in some project (controlflow and dataflow if it is useful for you). When I change tabs after modification graph in tab1 (tab2) I have problem with drawing standard endpoints on tab2 (tab1) which was created by jsPlumb endpoint constructor.  <br/> I know about demos of jsPlumb and use them =)

Comment: I don't use YUI, but quickly looked through tabview, so all you need is ability to draw graphs on different tabs? I have a very similar thing working in jquery. Why not create a `jsfiddle` demonstrating the issue with tabs, may be I can help better than.

Comment: Unfortunately I have large project without free licence. Problem with tabview next: if I programmatically delete node on deactive tab then all endpoints are moved to the left-top corner of parent division. By moving elements with endpoints they has correct positions but only after drag... Sorry for bad English =)

Comment: Why deleting nodes without deleting endpoints ? If you want to remove nodes at all, remove it completely (connections, endpoints followed by nodes)

Comment: Thanks for help) Probably my previous comment is not correct =) Sure deleting node allow to delete relating endpoint and connections. Problem with drawing other endpoints!